# Report Builder Month Function

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

In report builder how to filter a date field to get the current month? I'm looking for something equivalent to the `Today()` function (that gets you just today values).

Actually when I use `=field.date.value(Today())`, I get today date returned. I would like something like that for the current month instead of the current date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,where i am getting the month value from the date of birth field.

=Cstr(Month(Fields!DOB.Value))